# gradle always uses {user.home}/repository as maven local cache

Tags: maven, upload, gradle

I am using Gradle 1.12 and upload artifacts to internal maven repository using below configuration.

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            def url = "http://url_to_artifactory/"
            pom.version = version
            pom.artifactId = project.name
            pom.groupId = project.group
            repository(url: url) {
                authentication(userName: 'username', password: 'password')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have settings.xml file under ${HOME}/.m2

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>/path/to/repo</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Whenever I upload archives, gradle does not cache it to as I defined in settings.xml (path/to/repo) but to  .m2/repository

Any help will be much appreciated
Tuncay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem before. It's a bug in gradle which only affect upload and it's ok for install:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_maven_plugin_fails_to_install_to_local_repo

Maybe try maven-publish plugin